# How to run headless browser inside docker?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, docker

I am building a Crawler with headless browser But right now I want to dockerize my app I've installed chrome in my docker image But it throw me an error when run the script.

StartChrome.js

```
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');

chromeLauncher.launch({
    port: 9222,
    chromeFlags: ['--headless','--proxy-server=54.171.181.204:8888','--disable-web-security','--disable-gpu']
}).then(chrome => {
    console.log(`Chrome debugging port running on ${chrome.port}`);
});
```

Err

```
(node:415) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9222
(node:415) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

And when I run it in command line it throws me an error like this

```
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with a Docker Image like *yukinying/chrome-headless-browser* or similar: https://hub.docker.com/r/yukinying/chrome-headless-browser/

From the description:

> This docker image contain the Linux Dev channel Chromium
>   (https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel), with the
>   required dependencies and the command line arguments running headless
>   mode.